Cast a list of pointers to a list of constant pointers in C++
I have a class that needs to build / maintain a list of pointers to objects, but then should return a constant list to constant pointers to the same data.   So something like:
class Foo {
private:
   std::list<Word *>  myList;
public:
   const std::list<const Word *>  getList() { return myList; }
}

But if I compile that, I get an error:
error: cannot convert 'const std::__cxx11::list<Word*>*' to 'const std::__cxx11::list<const Word*>*' in return

Is there a way to cast a list of pointers to a list of constant pointers?

AFAIK it is not possible as such.

Obligatory nitpick, const Word* is not a constant pointer, Word* const is.

propagate const might be what you're looking for... Not sure what compilers support it though, MSVC does not.

types std::list<Word*> and std::list<Word const*> are unrelated you cannot cast between them. You can reinterpret_cast and const_cast but take care of side effects (at least all must be directly and indirectly const): reinterpret_cast<std::list<Word const*>const&>(myList).

Also imagine if this conversion was standard practice. You could then cast a const std::list<Word*>* (A) to a const std::list<const Word*>* (B) and modify the Word objects through A, violating the const-correctness of B. Good thing this isn’t standard practice.

Side note. Why use pointers at all (with proper move semantics) you can just use std::vector<Word> and then return a const std::vector<Word>&  (In other words don't use pointers unless you really have to)

@ChukwujiobiCanon -- You can do Word A("blah"); const Word *B = &A;  A.set("blahblah") which have the exact same const-correctness issue, except that is legal in C++.   In my case I want to be able to modify the list, but I don't want anyone receiving the list to be able to mess with it...

The you have to give them a new list.  Using { return {myList.begin(), myList.end()}; } might work, cant check right now.

@user11809993 good thing it isn’t standard practice. Besides that, what is the rationale behind returning a constant list of pointers to constant values? It might be an XY problem after all.

Return-by-value is almost always better than return-by-const-value.  (That advice is applicable in the domain of by value; which is quite different from return-by-reference and return-by-const-reference, either of which has common use case scenarios.)

I have a program with a large database of items, which are used by multiple entities in a program.  I have a producer class which is responsible for dynamically building a list containing a subset of these items (it needs to update each of the items to mark what lists they belong to, and update stats, etc, so it needs read-write access to each of the items).   Finally, I have several consumers who need to do operations based on these lists.   The consumers should only have read access to the list.   Hence, I want to pass a const list of pointers to const items to each of the consumers.

Will the producer manipulate Word instances via Word*? Is there anything wrong with the producer also holding const Word*s within the std::list?

@user11809993 -- then return a copy of the list with const pointers as somebody suggested above.

@ChukwujiobiCanon yes, it will modify each entry as it is placed on the list (and modify each entry when removed from the list as well).   The producer requires write access to each of the items.

@Gene -- each list contains up to 100000 entries, so I'd prefer not to copy them.   I will modify all the consumers to accept non-const pointers, and make them cast to const pointers before using them.

@user11809993 -- now it's confusing, your original code attempted to create a copy but didn't compile, now you are saying you don't want a copy. If you don't want a copy then don't return a list, provide functions to work on elements.


Is there a way to cast a list of pointers to a list of constant pointers?

As literally asked, no. list<T*> and list<T const *> are not similar in the same way that T* and T const* are similar.
If you can generalize to just returning something iterable (and you're using reasonably up-to-date C++) you can avoid copying the whole list like so:
auto getList() const
{
    return myList | std::views::transform(
        [](int *p) { return const_cast<int const *>(p); }
    );
}

Otherwise the usual solution is to hold almost anything in your list apart from raw pointers.
Anything with const-qualified methods that correctly propogate constness from a const iterator through to the final object will be fine - there are some examples on this rather elderly question, or you can find implementations of the std::experimental::propagate_const.

If you have access to ranges, @Useless answer should be preferred. Other alternatives are:

If you only need to return an iterable object, then you can make a custom iterator type that returns const pointer.
Or, you can store std::list<const Word *> inside Foo, and use const_cast to access the non-const pointer inside Foo implementation.

